# Bulk-create posts from SQL database

Tags: database, sql, bulk, bulk-import

I'm new in this forum and fairly new to Wordpress as a whole, so I hope I will abide by all written and unwritten rules when posting this.

I have an SQL database with around 4,000 posts from an old website. Each post has an ID, date, title, body, keywords, and category column (and some others that are irrelevant). These columns are, as far as I've seen it, not named in a default manner but are, at least in part, specific to the website's topic.

I want to create a completely new website with new hosting, new theme, new design etc.

Is there a possibility to auto-populate that new website with all the 4,000 posts from my SQL database through wordpress? So the ideal result would be to build my new website, then Wordpress-SQL-magic happens, and then when the website goes live it already has 4,000 posts that are accessible through the new menu, neatly categorized based on the categories in the SQL database and also displaying the date on which it was *originally* published. The categories in the SQL database are mere numbers, so they would have to be linked to the actual worded menu categories.

Maybe I'm missing something very basic here, because I do know that you can export all posts as an SQL file, but I have never bulk-uploaded anything to Wordpress, especially not from another site that has a different menu structure than the new one.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help you might be able to provide!

Comment: Is the old site WordPress as well?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. It's not my site, but I'm pretty sure it's wordpress-based.